# Parsing only specific values from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm parsing some information using Xpath and it returns me a simple array.

`$values = array();`

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.aaa.com/19364328526/
    [1] => http://www.bbb.com/207341152011/
    [2] => http://www.ccc.co.jp/1246623/
)
```

Is there any way I can parse through the array and only take certain URLs based on URL weighting? For example. If aaa.com exists, take only aaa.com. If not, check for ccc.co.jp, if that exists, take that only, etc.

I only know how to select from arrays when I know what is there $values[0]/[1]/etc, unfortunately the order of links in this array change and/or aren't present sometimes.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!
Tre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in_array()` to check if a value exists. I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but here is an example. Do you know all the possible values that you might get back?

```
//List domains in priority order    
$weighted = array('aaa.com','bbb.com','ccc.com');

$selected_url = '';
foreach($weighted as $check) { //start with highest priority
    foreach($values as $url) { //loop through all URL's
        if(strpos($url,$check) !== false) {
            //If a url matches priority, return it. We are finished to exit both loops
            $selected_url = $url;
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
```

`$selected_url` should have the highest priority URL, or it will be empty if none of the urls were found.

Comment: I'll be looping through a few array lists like that and I just want to strip out the highest weighted URL then plop it into an array which will be spit out at the end. I'll take a look at this. Thanks

Comment: How are you defining the weight of your URL's? That might make a difference

Comment: I haven't tried yet, hence the question. I basically was wondering if there was a way to scan the array sequentially. Check for aaa.com, if its there grab the full array entry aaa.com/xyz, etc. If its not there, check for ccc.co.jp, if it's there grab the full array entry, etc.

Comment: Oooh, ok let me edit my answer for you then. I thought of a better idea.

Comment: This method would allow you to define your own weighting by simply having high priority checks come first.  For your example you you could use `foreach` as above and `preg_match` to match the domain of interest.

Comment: @connec I updated my answer. Just a note, `strpos` is much more efficient that `preg_match` in this case, since we don't need any advanced functionality of regular expressions. From the [php manual](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php): Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster.

Comment: @Brian Glaz: I agree, I was working on the belief that there may (in rare cases, probably) be one of the other domains in the other... e.g. `http://aaa.com/bbb.com`.  I guess this is unlikely enough that `strpos` makes more sense in this situation.